# MongoDB & AMCharts

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amcharts

I am trying to create an AMchart with some values from my mongoDB using mongoose and Node.js. Since Node.js is asynchronous I can't pass my values from the query to the chart, If I put the chart creation inside the same function scope as the query when I do the  calling in the handlebars I get nothing since the chart creation is inside the query, but this is the onñy way I have been able to retrieve the data. My code is as follows:

```js
<script>
  var Edad = require('../models/edad');
 var data = [];
 Edad.find().lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
  if (err) throw err;
  data = docs;
  for (var i in data) {
   delete data[i]._id;
   delete data[i].__v;
  }
 });
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "patterns",
  "dataProvider": data,
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  } ],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "Edad: [[category]]: <b> Numero Vacunas: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "vacunas"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "edad",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

} );
</script>
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
 <div class="container">
     <article class="box post">
   <header>
    <h2>Vacunas Por Edad</h2>
    <p>Estadisticas para el numero de vacunas aplicadas por cada grupo de edad de los pacientes</p>
   </header>
            <div id="chartdiv"></div>
        </article>
 </div>
</div>
```

I Need the data from the JSON "data" to be the value for "data provider" in the chart creation, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please tell me you are not actually querying mongoDB in a script tag.

Comment: No I'm not, I'm actually passing the data through a GET and then rendering the handlebars with the data. I just wrote it here in the script in order to write just one segment of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build the chart and then add the data later using [validateNow](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#validateNow):

```html
<script>
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "patterns",
    "dataProvider": [],
    "valueAxes": [ {
      "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
      "gridAlpha": 0.2,
      "dashLength": 0
    } ],
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [ {
      "balloonText": "Edad: [[category]]: <b> Numero Vacunas: [[value]]</b>",
      "fillAlphas": 0.8,
      "lineAlpha": 0.2,
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "vacunas"
    } ],
    "chartCursor": {
      "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
      "cursorAlpha": 0,
      "zoomable": false
    },
    "categoryField": "edad",
    "categoryAxis": {
      "gridPosition": "start",
      "gridAlpha": 0,
      "tickPosition": "start",
      "tickLength": 20
    },
    "export": {
      "enabled": true
    }

  } );

  var Edad = require('../models/edad');
 Edad.find().lean().exec(function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (var i in data) {
   delete data[i]._id;
   delete data[i].__v;
  }
    
    chart.validateNow(data, false);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually it does not work, it renders the chart without any value inside, just a blank chart. I think it is due to node.js being aynchronous, I already tried using futures and async but same thing happens